# Redis StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException on debugging

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Why when I debugging in Visual studio I always get exception StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException if I force use redis in immediate windows or trying  to move debugging line to line wher I use redis.

If I use step in to or step over and I nothing change manually everythings is work correctly and redis respons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is caused due to:

1/ StackExchange.Redis have relatively short timeout by default

2/ Debugging cause threads to be suspended

The break point is hit and you are spending time inspecting states while StackExchange.Redis keep counting time ( The timer is not paused )

The solution for this is to change the timeouts configurations based on 
[Debugger.IsAttached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=netframework-4.8)

If you detect debugger is attached, change the [configuration](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html) of syncTimeout, connectTimeout to higher number

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to see. The qu (queue unsent) and queue are both 3 in this case, which indicates that the command wasn't even sent to Redis, which is why you are getting a timeout on the client side.

```
'mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 3, qu: 3, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0
```

Comment: Ok, but what do I need to do to get it working, because now I have a big problem when I manipulate code when I debugging.